# How to declare more than one function in a list?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

My code:

```
eq = {x + y - z == -1, x^2 + y^2 - z == 3};
sol1 = Eliminate[eq, z]
sol2 = Solve[sol1, y]
```

At this point I would like to define to functions $y(x)$ to get theri domain with FunctionDomain. But I get an error typing this line:

```
{a1[x_], a2[x_]} :=  {y /. sol2}
```

The problem is that the two lists are not of the same type. How can I explain that the right term is a function in x?

Comment: Try `{a1[x_], a2[x_]} := Evaluate[y /. sol2]`. You can check the definitions with `?a1` and `?a2`.

Comment: The major issue was that `SetDelayed` has the attribute `HoldAll`. In particular, `{a1[x_], a2[x_]} :=  y /. sol2` cannot _see_ that the right hand side is also a list of length 2. This is what gets remedied by `Evaluate`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It works!! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to define functions to find the domain

```
eq = {x + y - z == -1, x^2 + y^2 - z == 3};

sol = y /. Solve[eq, y, {z}]
```

(* {1/2 (1 - Sqrt[17 + 4 x - 4 x^2]), 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[17 + 4 x - 4 x^2])} *)

They have a common domain as shown with [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html)

```
fd = Union[FunctionDomain[#, x] & /@ sol]

(* {1/2 (1 - 3 Sqrt[2]) <= x <= 1/2 (1 + 3 Sqrt[2])} *)

Plot[Evaluate@Reverse@sol, {x, fd[[1, 1]], fd[[1, -1]]},
 Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.62, .6}]]
```

[image]

You could also just plot `sol` rather than `Evaluate@Reverse@sol` but the `PlotLegends` would then be upside down compared with their curves.